# Mounted the AWS CLI credentials as volume to docker container however still credentials are not being referred

Tags: docker, dockerfile, aws-cli

I have created a docker image using AmazonLinux:2 base image in my Dockerfile. This docker container will run as Jenkins build agent on a Linux server and has to make certain AWS API calls. In my Dockerfile, I'm copying a shell-script called assume-role.sh.
Code snippet:-

```
COPY ./assume-role.sh .
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "assume-role.sh"]
ENTRYPOINT ["/assume-role.sh"]
CMD ["bash", "--"]
```

Shell script definition:-

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#echo Your container args are: "${1} ${2} ${3} ${4} ${5}"
echo Your container args are: "${1}"
ROLE_ARN="${1}"
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="${2:-us-east-1}"
SESSIONID=$(date +"%s")
DURATIONSECONDS="${3:-3600}"

#Temporary loggings starts here
id
pwd
ls .aws
cat .aws/credentials
#Temporary loggings ends here

# AWS STS AssumeRole
RESULT=(`aws sts assume-role --role-arn $ROLE_ARN \
        --role-session-name $SESSIONID \
  --duration-seconds $DURATIONSECONDS \
        --query '[Credentials.AccessKeyId,Credentials.SecretAccessKey,Credentials.SessionToken]' \
        --output text`)

# Setting up temporary creds
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${RESULT[0]}
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${RESULT[1]}
export AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN=${RESULT[2]}
export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=${AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN}
echo 'AWS STS AssumeRole completed successfully'

# Making test AWS API calls
aws s3 ls
echo 'test calls completed'
```

I'm running the docker container like this:-

```
docker run -d -v $PWD/.aws:/.aws:ro -e XDG_CACHE_HOME=/tmp/go/.cache arn:aws:iam::829327394277:role/myjenkins test-image
```

What I'm trying to do here is mounting **.aws** credentials from host directory to the volume on container at root level. The volume mount is successful and I can see the log outputs as describe in its shell file :-

```
ls .aws
cat .aws/credentials
```

It tells me there is a **.aws** folder with credentials inside it in the root level (/). However somehow, AWS CLI is not picking up and as a result remaining API calls like AWS STS assume-role is getting failed.

Can somebody please suggest me here?

**[Output of docker run]**

```
Your container args are: arn:aws:iam::829327394277:role/myjenkins
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
/
config
credentials
[default]
aws_access_key_id = AKXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXP
aws_secret_access_key = e8SYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYxYm
Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".
AWS STS AssumeRole completed successfully

Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".
test calls completed
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: @gohm'c I''m getting this error 'Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".' I have updated my Question with output of Docker run above and if you see there, cat command is printing the values and list command is able to list the files and also my present working directory is root (/). Just wondering instead of root, .aws should comes inside the /home/<user id> directory or some other issue?

Comment: You probably don't have to re-invent the wheel, checkout the answer if it helps you.

Comment: @gohm'c does this image support AWS STS AssumeRole out of box?

Comment: @gohm'c I need my image to have AWS STS support hence I was using the customized image. Can you pls tell me if this aws-cli image supports AWS STS AssumeRole or not? Thanks

Comment: @gohm'c, I found the issue finally, the path was wrong while mounting the volume. It was supposed to be -v $PWD/.aws:/root/.aws:ro. The root was missing. It is working now. thanks

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue finally.

The path was wrong while mounting the .aws volume to the container.

Instead of this `-v $PWD/.aws:/.aws:ro`, it was supposed to be `-v $PWD/.aws:/root/.aws:ro`

Comment: For me it mounts the .aws directory but inside docker credentials is a directory. I cant even use cat on it inside docker. On host machine credentials is a file with valid profiles